# tomcat with jsp

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have compiled my program `Hello.java` using Tomcat 5.5.9.
But it is not running onto the browser.

It is showing message

> "the requested resource(\Hello) is not available".

I have placed `Hello.java` inside the folder `C:\ProgramFiles\Tomcat\tomcat-5.5.9\Webapps\servlets-examples\WEB-INF\classes\Hello.java`.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: please post your web.xml

Comment: <web-app>

      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Hello</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/servlet/Hello</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    </web-app>

Comment: I have added this to my web.xml file...

Comment: change url-pattern to `/Hello`, and re start your tomcat

Comment: ya i have made the changes but its not working...

Comment: and there should be a servlet class Hello.class in your `WEB-INF/classes/`

Comment: but its not running, still showing error message. Hw can i resolve it???

Comment: is there any exception message on your tomcat console ??

Comment: ya its showing message  "HTTP Status 404 - /Hello

type Status report

message /Hello

description The requested resource (/Hello) is not available.
Apache Tomcat/5.5.9".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Deployment Descriptor(web.xml) can be found at this location

`C:\ProgramFiles\Tomcat\tomcat-5.5.9\Webapps\servlets-examples\WEB-INF\`

If it is not present make one.

Make sure your  deployment descriptor contain the following lines

```
<web-app>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Hello</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Hello</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

---

Look you have used the url pattern as `<url-pattern>/servlet/Hello</url-pattern>`.

A url pattern cannot contain '/' in the name, either make it `/servlet_Hello` or just `/Hello`

---

**Edit**

**The pattern `/Hello` is Case Sensitive.**
So make sure it is the same as it is in your `<url-pattern>/Hello</url-pattern>`

Stop the TomCat Server , make changes to your Deployment Descriptor, recompile Hello.java file, start the server and type the url, it shold be working now.

---

**Edit**

URL should be

`http://localhost:8080/servlets-examples/Hello`

considering that your servlet is located at
`C:\ProgramFiles\Tomcat\tomcat-5.5.9\Webapps\servlets-examples\WEB-INF\classes\`

Comment: ya i have added this to my web.xml file. But its still not running. Its showing message" the requested resource is not available".

Comment: I have made the changes but its working

Comment: ya i restart tomcat but it still showing error message

Comment: can you post the error message?

Comment: ya its showing message"HTTP Status 404 - /Hello

type Status report

message /Hello

description The requested resource (/Hello) is not available.
Apache Tomcat/5.5.9".

Comment: I have edited the answer take a look.

Comment: ya i have edited but still getting the same problem.

Comment: Is your class public? For example `public class Hello extends HttpServlet{  }`

Comment: i dont know why bt its not working..

Comment: Have you declared your class `public` ?

Comment: ya i have made it public like import javax.servlet.*;               import java.io.*;                                              public class Hello extends GenericServlet                          { public void  service(ServletRequest request,ServletResponse response) throws ServletException , IOException                    { response.setContentType("text/html");                   PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();                        pw.println("<B>Hello");pw.close();                                     }}

Comment: where is the problem, i didnt get it.

Comment: plz check out the code for Hello.java if there is any problem then let me knw.

Comment: The code is working. *Stop the TomCat Server , make changes to your Deployment Descriptor, recompile Hello.java file, start the server and type the url, it shold be working.*

Comment: Did you note that URL pattern is case sensitive, that means `/Hello` **is not same as** `/hello`      And you will get an error `The requested resource (/hello) is not available.`

Comment: yes i hav done dat and typed url "http:\\localhost:8080\Hello" but it is displaying the error message.

Comment: what have you typed in the `<url-pattern></url-pattern>`. copy paste it as it is over here.

Comment: <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Hello</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

Comment: Oh wait! You said your java file is in `C:\ProgramFiles\Tomcat\tomcat-5.5.9\Webapps\servlets-examples\WEB-INF\classes\Hello.java` then your URL will be `http://localhost:8080/servlets-examples/Hello` This will definetly work.

Answer (score 0):

Heres an sample example

*Hello.java*

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Hello extends HttpServlet{

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) 
                                        throws ServletException,IOException{
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
        out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

---

*web.xml*

```
<web-app>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>Hello</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/Hello</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

---